# Async/Await createReadStream end before read all data : Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, stream

I'm using `fs.createReadStream` to read uploaded csv file data.When data row received,I'm validate those data and push validated data in to the array.

The issue was,it's receive final row after called `end`.

I've use csv with four rows for for bellow test.All four records are validation pass.

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on("error", (error) => {
        throw error.message;
    })
    .on("data", async (row) => {
        try {
            stream.pause();
            const mobile = Helper.validateMobile(row.Telephone)

            const validationerrors = await Helper.ValidateCustomer(null, mobile, row.code, "BULK");

            console.log(`validationerrors ---> ${validationerrors} Telephone--> ${row.Telephone}`)

            if (validationerrors.length) {
                throw validationerrors.message

            } else {
                csvData.push(row);
            }
        } finally {
            stream.resume();
        }
    })
    .on("end", async () => {
        console.log("ENDDD ---->", csvData)
    });
```

`Console.log` out put is like this.Final row (row with 777223478) receive after `on("end")` calls.

```
    validationerrors --->  Telephone--> 778786516
    validationerrors --->  Telephone--> 718254596 
    validationerrors --->  Telephone--> 712760763 
    
    ENDDD ----> [ 
       { 
        Code: 'CTLD000323',',   
        Telephone: '778786516' }, 
       { 
        Code: 'CTLD000324',  
        Telephone: '718254596' }, 
       { 
        Code: 'CTLD000376',    
        Telephone: '712760763' } 
      ] 
    
    validationerrors --->  Telephone--> 777223478
```

Comment: I wonder if it's because of the `.pipe()` and thus you may not be pausing the right stream or if the CSV module is not properly respecting the `.pause()`?  Which csv module on NPM are you using so we can look at its code and doc?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer  .  Also followed this example https://github.com/dabelsare/upload-csv-into-node-server/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Multer isn't your csv implementation.  That example uses `const csv = require('fast-csv');`.  Is that what you're using?

Comment: yes it is using inside pipe like `.pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true })))`

Comment: It appears to me that the csv parser you are using does not support `.pause()` properly and it will keep sending you processed rows that are in the buffer, even after you've paused the stream.  All I can think of is that you have to buffer `data` events when you want to be paused and not process them until you are ready to.

Comment: yes.but i've tried `csv-parse` module as well.but same thing happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it appears that the CSV library does not respect the `.pause()` method and if it has multiple rows queued up, it goes ahead and fires `data` events for them, even if the stream is paused.  The two ways I know of to fix that are to modify the csv module to respect the stream pause or to queue up line as they come in so you can manually pause processing of them when you are already in the middle of processing something.  And, you also have to queue up the `end` event since the stream will send it before you're done processing.  I've handled the end event by synthesizing my own `finalEnd` event.  Here's a rough implementation of a queue that buffers `data` events that arrive while the stream is paused.

```
let paused = false;
const queue = [];
let end = false;

const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on("error", (error) => {
        throw error.message;
    })
    .on("data", async (row) => {
        queue.push(row);
        if (!paused) {
            stream.pause();
            paused = true;
            while (queue.length) {
                try {
                    await processRow(queue.shift());
                } catch (e) {
                    // decide what to do here if you get an error processing a row
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
            paused = false;
            stream.resume();
            if (end) {
                stream.emit("finalEnd");
            }
        }

        async function processRow(row) {
            const mobile = Helper.validateMobile(row.Telephone)

            const validationerrors = await Helper.ValidateCustomer(null, mobile, row.code, "BULK");

            console.log(`validationerrors ---> ${validationerrors} Telephone--> ${row.Telephone}`)

            if (validationerrors.length) {
                throw validationerrors.message

            } else {
                csvData.push(row);
            }
        }

    })
    .on("end", async () => {
        end = true;
        if (!queue.length && !paused) {
            stream.emit("finalEnd");
        }
    }).on("finalEnd", () => {
        console.log("ENDDD ---->", csvData)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you.now it's called `finalEnd` twice and second time  `csvData` array completed with all four records.

Comment: @Tje123 - See update that prevents the double `finalEnd` event.  I had to make sure we weren't still paused and processing the last line before emitting `finalEnd`.

Comment: Thank you.Really appreciate your help.Now its working as expected.