# Correctly use fs write inside createReadStream on data

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I am attempting to combine `n` binary files into a single file in javascript using streams. I have a write stream that is passed to the following function. I notice that the total written bytes does not match the actual number of bytes in the file, and is also not consistent across multiple runs.

After reading the documentation, I noticed that the `write` call returns a promise and is not safe to be called again until the previous promise is fulfilled. I am not sure how to make `readStream.on('data', function (chunk)` use `await`, as the function is not async and I get an error `await is only valid in async function`

```
async function concatFile (filename, fileHandle) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, { highWaterMark: 1024 })

    readStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
      // read
      fileHandle.write(chunk)
    })
    readStream.on('error', e => {
      reject(e)
    })
    readStream.on('close', function (err) {
      // close
    })
    readStream.on('end', function () {
      // done
      readStream.close()
      resolve()
    })
  }) // end of Promise
}
```

I am using the above function in the following snippet:

```
  const fileWriter = fs.createWriteStream('concatBins.bin', { flags: 'w' })
  let writtenLen = 0
  fileList = {}
  fileList[0] = "foo.bin"
  fileList[1] = "bar.bin"
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fileList)) {
    await concatFile(value, fileWriter)
    writtenLen = fileWriter.bytesWritten
    console.log('bytes written ' + writtenLen)
  }
```

Comment: You can [pause](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) the readStream until the write is done to avoid getting future `data` events and the [resume](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) it when done with the write.  And, you can declare the `.on('data', ...)` callback to be `async` if you want to use `await`.  But, you do have to pause the readStream because the async/await won't pause it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [pause](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) the readStream until the write is done to avoid getting future `data` events and the [resume](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) it when done with the write. And, you can declare the `.on('data', ...)` callback to be `async` if you want to use `await`. But, you do have to pause the readStream because the async/await won't pause it for you.

```
// stream write that returns a promise when OK to proceed
// with more writes
function write(stream, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         if (stream.write(data)) {
             resolve();
         } else {
             // need to wait for drain event
             stream.once('drain', resolve);
         }
         
    });
}

async function concatFile (filename, writeStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, { highWaterMark: 1024 });
    let paused = false;
    let ended = false;

    readStream.on('data', async function(chunk) {
      // read
      try {
        readStream.pause();
        paused = true;
        await write(writeStream, chunk);
      } catch(e) {
        // have to decide what you're doing if you get a write  error here
        reject(e);
      } finally {
        paused = false;
        readStream.resume();
        if (ended) {
            readStream.emit("finalEnd");
        }
      }
    });
    readStream.on('error', e => {
      reject(e)
    })
    readStream.on('close', function (err) {
      // close
    })
    readStream.on('end', function () {
      // done
      ended = true;
      if (!paused) {
         readStream.emit('finalEnd');
      }
    });
    // listen for our real end event
    readStream.on('finalEnd', () {
       readStream.close();
       resolve()
    });
  }) // end of Promise
}
```

Comment: thanks! i think i will still need to handle the fact that the write call has a callback to which it returns the result..

Comment: @rookie - [This version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_write_buffer_offset_length_position) of `fileHandle.write()` uses a promise, not a callback so it works well with `await`.

Comment: I think it is working better than before, but i am using it in the snippet (added as an edit), but i see that `writtenLen` is not in sync with the cumulative sum of the individual file sizes. I am getting different `writtenLen` values when i run the code multiple times

Comment: @rookie - Also, there are cases where the `end` event can occur while the stream is paused (which would be before you're done writing) which could cause problems if you're going onto the next write before the previous one was done.  This is all much easier if you use a stream for the writing rather than a plain FileHandle object.  You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219825/async-await-createreadstream-end-before-read-all-data-node-js/68220376#68220376) that deals with the issue of the `end` event occurring while the stream is paused.

Comment: @rookie - Also your code has me thoroughly confused.  You show the creation of a writeStream named `fileWriter`, but then you are writing to a variable named `fileHandle`.  Which is it?  Where does `fileHandle` come from?  If that's not really a fileHandle, but is actually a stream, then you will need to handle the `write()` differently as it doesn't return a promise (you can promisify it).  Naming is EVERYTHING in having clear code so naming a stream object as fileHandle is very misleading if that's what you actually did here.

Comment: @rookie - OK, I think I now understand that you are actually using a writeStream, not a fileHandle so I've updated my answer to show that and to address another possible issue with the `end` event occurring before you're done with the writing.

Comment: I apologize, I understand that the `fileHandle` is not the right term to use here, that's from my lack of understanding of (still new at this). Thank you for patiently helping me through this